# Why laravel elequent relation not requering on second call

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, oop

I have relation Wallet model which is related to User in many-to-one relationship.

I made a relation on User model Named wallet
Then in controller,

1. I called the relation like $user->wallet to show some wallet data
2. Insert some data in wallet table
3. recalled the $user->wallet

But surprisingly, the $user->wallet returning the same data as previous call even though I inserted a new row. I dont see the any new row.

Comment: Please provide the `User` model file and the code you used to select and insert the wallet relationship :)

Comment: This is the intended behavior. You can reload the relationship with `$user->load('wallet');`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thanks for the response. 
Can I chain other methods followed by load()?

Comment: Yes, you can. `load()` returns `$this`.